# Why doesn't "x = a or b" work in Perl?

Tags: perl

In other languages I would write

```
testvar = onecondition OR anothercondition;
```

to have testvar be true if either condition is. But in Perl this does not work as expected.

I want to check a condition where either a content-variable is empty, or it matches a specific regex. I have this sample program:

```
my $contents = "abcdefg\n";
my $criticalRegEx1 = qr/bcd/;
my $cond1 = ($contents eq "");
my $cond2 = ($contents =~ $criticalRegEx1);
my $res = $cond1 or $cond2;
if($res) {print "One or the other is true.\n";}
```

I would have expected $res to contain "1" or something that evals to true when tested with if(). But it contains the empty string.

How can I achieve this in Perl?

Comment: Check out the [operator precedence table](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity). Compare `or` with `||`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put parentheses around expression,

```
my $res = ($cond1 or $cond2);
```

or use higher precedence `||` operator,

```
my $res = $cond1 || $cond2;
```

as your code is interpreted by Perl as `(my $res = $cond1) or $cond2;`, or more accurately,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$res = $cond1 or $cond2;'
$cond2 unless $res = $cond1;
```

If you were using `use warnings;` it would also warn you regarding `$cond2`,

```
Useless use of a variable in void context
```

Comment: Interestingly, the `or` keyword was added to Perl when people complained about the opposite problem.  Perl 4 only had `||` and no `or`.

Comment: I use warnings in my code and got the warning. However in the real code (not this test code) the statements are not splitted up like here so I never got the warning there. And above that, I did not understand what it tried to tell me :) Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: @jackthehipster `use diagnostics;` will be more descriptive regarding warning.

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything correct. Just put braces for `$cond1 or $cond2` as shown in the below code:

```
my $contents = "abcdefg\n";
my $criticalRegEx1 = qr/bcd/;
my $cond1 = ($contents eq "");
my $cond2 = ($contents =~ $criticalRegEx1);
my $res = ($cond1 or $cond2);
if($res) {print "One or the other is true.\n";}
```